# Error: non-aggregate type 'vector<int>' cannot be initialized with an initializer list

Tags: c++, vector

I am a beginner in c++ and every time I run `vector<int> nums = {2, 5, 3, 7, 1};` it gives me the Error: non-arregrate type vector cannot be initialized with initializer list.

Can you tell me why?

Thanks,

Comment: Most likely you need to turn on C++11 or higher.

Comment: Can you tell me how to turn it on on a mac?

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are you compiling?

Comment: I am using gcc on the compiler

Comment: @ian just pass `-std=c++11`.

Comment: it said command not found.

Comment: You need to pass it as an option to the compiler, e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 prog.cpp`.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Use `g++ -std=c++11 <filename>` when compiling.

Answer (score 8):

Using Druhv Sehgal's answer above, this worked for me on mac

If `command not found: gcc++` try

`clang++ -std=c++11 <filename>`

Comment: Where can I read about -std flag? I read http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cburch/211-sp96/gnu_devel/gpp.html , but didn't found that option.

Comment: I found this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html, which has some options. I've only ever used c++11 so I'm not expert. This looks good too https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are using VS code, then go to settings.json, Add
"-std=c++17", "-stdlib=libc++" in the args array.

[Attached the screenshot of the settings.json for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/det0F.png)